# Capturar entrada digitada pelo usuário com Shell PHP

Tags: php, script

Como posso fazer para que resgate dados da entrada.

Exemplo:

```
> Qual seu nome?

...Usuário digita o seu nome...

> Olá, $nome-digitado
```

Como posso fazer isso via `Shell Script` em `PHP`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acredito que o que você quer é:

```
<?php
echo "Qual seu nome?";
$stdin = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$nome = fgets($stdin);
echo "Olá,", $nome, "!";
?>
```

Para entradas mais complexas você pode utilizar a função fscanf. Mais informações podem ser encontradas na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.io-streams.php).

Comment: Podendo também se usar `fgets(STDIN)` direto, dado que a constante `STDIN` armazena o valor do arquivo `php://stdin`

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função [readline()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readline.php)

Veja o exemplo;

```
$nome = readline("Qual o seu nome?: ");
```

Você pode também adicionar as os dados de entrada para ter uma lista completa com `readline_add_history($sua_variavel);` e depois ver todas elas com `readline_list_history()`

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo simples que você pode fazer para usar é criar algumas funções (para fazer semelhante ao goto no cmd) e usar o [`STDIN`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) (que é uma atalho para `fopen('php://stdin', 'r')`) ficando algo assim:

```
<?php
//Se a pessoa digitar "foo" chama esta função
function foo() {
    echo 'Foo', PHP_EOL;
    Pergunta();
}

//Se a pessoa digitar "sair" chama esta função
function sair() {
    exit;
}

function Pergunta() {
    echo 'O que deseja fazer?', PHP_EOL;

    $comando = trim(fgets(STDIN)); //Pega o que o usuário digitou

    if (empty($comando) === false && is_callable($comando)) {
        $comando();
    } else {
        echo 'Comando não existe', PHP_EOL;
        Pergunta(); //Se a função não existir pergunta novamente
    }
}

Pergunta(); //Inicia a função
```

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não está muito clara, se é usando `PHP` junto com Shell Script (outra linguagem), ou se é usando o `PHP CLI` (por linha de comando), por isso vou citar os dois casos.

Usando a linguagem `Shell Script` com a linguagem `PHP` ficaria:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Digite seu nome"
read nome
echo "Olá, " . $nome
```

Usando o `PHP CLI`, para ler uma linha só da entrada:

```
<?php
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN)); // Recebe uma linha da entrada
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $number); // Recebe número dado na entrada
?>
```

Veja mais em: [PHP: Uso da linha de comando](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.php)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, isso mesmo, passou em branco aqui, obrigado pela nota. Vou corrigir.